# In netsuite advanced pdf templates is there anyway to Limit characters in a string

Tags: pdf, netsuite, freemarker

I need to Limit the characters in this field `${label.displayname}` around 40.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this with a FreeMarker [slicing expression](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_stringop_slice) -

`${label.displayname[0..39]}`

Comment: code is not working,getting an error in netsuite                    Range end index 39 is out of bounds, because the sliced string has only 16 character(s). (Note that indices are 0-based).
The blamed expression:
==> 0..39 [in template "template" at line 49, column 39] only give limit between [0-16]

Comment: @marg Then use `label.displayname[0..*39]`. The number after the `*` is the maximum length of the substring, rather than the last index.

Comment: perfectly working but its counting white spaces also.Is there any way to avoid that

Comment: how to avoid white-spaces while using the above code